# Group subsets of data in 3-level array by identifying column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

I've this type of array in PHP:

```
Array(
     [100] => Array(
          [1] => Array (
               [AVA_Date] => 2019-04-18
               [ROO_Id] => 100
               [RAT_Id] => 9
          )
          [2] => Array (
               [AVA_Date] => 2019-04-20
               [ROO_Id] => 100
               [RAT_Id] => 10
          )
          [4] => Array (
               [AVA_Date] => 2019-04-21
               [ROO_Id] => 100
               [RAT_Id] => 10
          )
          [7] => Array (
               [AVA_Date] => 2019-04-22
               [ROO_Id] => 100
               [RAT_Id] => 9
          )
     )
)
```

I would like to merge items on `ROO_Id` and `RAT_Id`.

Then, for the `AVA_Date`, I need to list them under a new array in the current array.

So, the desired output is:

```
Array(
     [100] => Array(
          [0] => Array (
               [AVA_Date] => Array (
                    [0] => 2019-04-18
                    [1] => 2019-04-22
               )
               [ROO_Id] => 100
               [RAT_Id] => 9
          )
          [1] => Array (
               [AVA_Date] => Array (
                    [0] => 2019-04-20
                    [1] => 2019-04-21
               )
               [ROO_Id] => 100
               [RAT_Id] => 10
          )
     )
)
```

Here what I have tried:

```
$newArrOtherRooms  = array_reduce($newArr, function($acc, $val) {
    $room = array_search($val['ROO_Id'], array_column($acc, 'ROO_Id'));
    $rate = array_search($val['RAT_Id'], array_column($acc, 'RAT_Id'));
    if($rate == $room && $room > -1) {
        array_push($acc[$room]['AVA_Date'], $val['AVA_Date']);
    }
    else {
        $new_arr = $val;
        $new_arr['AVA_Date'] = [$val['AVA_Date']];
        array_push($acc, $new_arr);
    }
    return $acc;
},[]);
```

But it doesn't work like I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. Firstly, you need to wrap the [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) with a `foreach` over the outer level of `$newArr`. Secondly, your call to [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) doesn't consider the fact that a `ROO_Id` or `RAT_Id` value might exist more than once in the array, as it only returns the first key at which it finds the value. To work around this, you can use [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get an array of key values for each `ROO_Id` and `RAT_Id` value, and then take the intersection of those two arrays using [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to see if both are present in the same element. If so, you update that element, otherwise you create a new one:

```
foreach ($newArr as $key => $array) {
    $newArrOtherRooms[$key]  = array_reduce($array, function($acc, $val) {
        $room = array_keys(array_column($acc, 'ROO_Id'), $val['ROO_Id']);
        $rate = array_keys(array_column($acc, 'RAT_Id'), $val['RAT_Id']);
        $common = array_intersect($room, $rate);
        if(!empty($common)) {
            array_push($acc[current($common)]['AVA_Date'], $val['AVA_Date']);
        }
        else {
            $new_arr = $val;
            $new_arr['AVA_Date'] = [$val['AVA_Date']];
            array_push($acc, $new_arr);
        }
        return $acc;
    },[]);
}
print_r($newArrOtherRooms);
```

Output:

```
Array(
     [100] => Array(
          [0] => Array (
               [AVA_Date] => Array (
                    [0] => 2019-04-18
                    [1] => 2019-04-22
               )
               [ROO_Id] => 100
               [RAT_Id] => 9
          )
          [1] => Array (
               [AVA_Date] => Array (
                    [0] => 2019-04-20
                    [1] => 2019-04-21
               )
               [ROO_Id] => 100
               [RAT_Id] => 10
          )
     )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/IgG03)

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to be making all of those iterated function calls.

Use a nested loop to iterate the subset of data for each room, group on the room "rate id", and push all "available date" values into a subarray in the respective group.  When the subset of data is fully iterated, push its grouped data into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/c1VBX))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($newArr as $rooId => $rows) {
    $groups = [];
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if (!isset($groups[$row['RAT_Id']])) {
            $row['AVA_Date'] = (array) $row['AVA_Date'];
            $groups[$row['RAT_Id']] = $row;
        } else {
            $groups[$row['RAT_Id']]['AVA_Date'][] = $row['AVA_Date'];
        }
    }
    $result[$rooId] = array_values($groups);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  100 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'AVA_Date' => 
      array (
        0 => '2019-04-18',
        1 => '2019-04-22',
      ),
      'ROO_Id' => 100,
      'RAT_Id' => 9,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'AVA_Date' => 
      array (
        0 => '2019-04-20',
        1 => '2019-04-21',
      ),
      'ROO_Id' => 100,
      'RAT_Id' => 10,
    ),
  ),
)
```